# Getting checkbox values through form POSTing

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am trying to get a checkbox value from a form. The checkbox is a "do you wish to sign-up to our newsletter" type box.

I have managed to get it to work but only when the box is ticked with the following code:

```
$signUp = $_POST['sign-up'][0];
if ($signUp !== 'Yes'){
    $signUp = 'No';
}
```

The checkbox looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sign-up" name="sign-up[]" value="Yes" />
```

The problem is that if the box is **not** checked then I get an undefined error.

What's the correct way of inferring whether the box has been checked or not? I only need to send the "No" value onwards in an email hence why I have hardcoded this text into the variable.

**How do I get the value of a checkbox, either checked or unchecked, in PHP**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this -

```
$signUp = !empty($_POST['sign-up'][0]) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; // Will check if the checkbox is checked or posted
```

No need of - `if ($signUp !== 'Yes'){`

And if it a single `checkbox` then -

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sign-up" name="sign-up" value="Yes" />
```

And

```
$signUp = !empty($_POST['sign-up']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['sign-up'][0]) && !empty($_POST['sign-up'][0]))
{
    $signUp = 'Yes';
}
else
{
    $signUp = 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `[]` on the end of the name tells PHP that you want the results in an array (and implies you are expecting multiple results).

This means you need to do two checks:

- Are *any* values checked?
- Which values are checked?

Such:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sign-up'])) {
        $signUp = $_POST['sign-up'][0];
        if ($signUp !== 'Yes'){
            $signUp = 'No';
        }
    }
```

If you aren't sending multiple values (which having "Yes" as a value implied) then remove the `[]` from the name and then you can just use `isset($_POST['sign-up'])` as your only test.

Comment: _“Which values are checked?”_ – that is difficult to determine if the input field name is just `sign-up[]`, because as we all know for unchecked checkboxes no name=value pair will be submitted at all. So to be able to tell _which_ checkboxes where checked, one should specify the index upfront, `name="sign-up[0]"`, `name="sign-up[1]"` etc. (or a non-zero-based/non-numeric index, if more appropriate for the data structure.)